# How to create a Discord channel in a specific category?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
    name = ctx.message.author
    category = discord.CategoryChannel.id=660809715818823690
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(str(name), overwrites=overwrites, category=category)
```

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'`
I don't understand what type of data the `category` parameter takes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you don't know that `channel` can mean one of the following:

[PrivateChannel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.PrivateChannel) (DMChannel, GroupChannel) and [GuildChannel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel) (TextChannel, VoiceChannel, CategoryChannel)

So if you do [get_channel](http://%60get_channel%60) it's not just for 'channels' but for categories as well.

So the parameter that [create_text_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel) takes for category is of type [CategoryChannel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel) and as we said previously we can get that by using `get_channel`:

`category_channel = bot.get_channel(660809715818823690)`

Where `bot` is the name you used for your bot instance.

Answer (score 0):

Without a full traceback, it's difficult to determine how exactly you're encountering that error. However, [`Guild.create_text_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel) accepts a [`CategoryChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel) as its `category` parameter.

You're setting `category` to the integer`660809715818823690`.
You're also modifying the discord.py class itself, something you should not be doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the channel per [`Guild.create_text_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel) you need to set the `category` parameter to a category that you can get for example from `message.channel.category` or [`channel.category`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.category) (the link's solution works for both, text and voice channels) and **not** like Harmon758 said to an integer.

(I am not sure if you can get the category without a channel or message)